# when using for /f - "was unexpected at this time"

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code in a batch file named test.bat:

```
SET TEMP_PATH=%1%
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in {%TEMP_PATH%"} do set PATH=%%a &set REVISION=%%b
```

when calling in cmd `test.bat somelongstring:123456`

I get:

```
{somelongstring:123456"} do set PATH=%a &set REVISION=%b was unexpected at this time.
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

use `(`, `)` instead of `{`, `}`.

`{`,`}` are not proper syntax for `for`